# enable “Turn off Windows+X hotkeys” GPO using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Need to enable `Turn off Windows+X hotkeys` GPO. I have used the below query but is not enabling the GPO.

```
If (-not (Get-Module GroupPolicy)){Import-Module GroupPolicy}
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "TestGPO Startup"-Key "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" -ValueName NoWinKeys -Value 1 -Type DWORD
```

I need to enable the GPO for specific group of users. So i can't use the below script since it will disable the shortcut keys for all the users.

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" -Name NoWinKeys -PropertyType DWord -Value 1
```

Please help me to enable `Turn off Windows+X hotkeys GPO`

Comment: `HKCU:` keys are for the "Current User" only. Can you confirm again that the script  actually applies this change to all users? If the issue is with an Active Directory GPO instead, please clarify that in the question because scoping a GPO to a group is done differently.

Comment: @user19702, I need to enable the mentioned GPO. That's the aim. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "Test-GPO" -Key "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" -ValueName NoWinKeys -Value 1 -Type DWORD

Set-GPRegistryValue : The following key is not valid for a Group Policy registry setting: 
"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer". The key must be in one of 
the following registry hives: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Make sure that the 
Key parameter contains a valid key. Then, run the command again.
```

So try using the corrected path:

```
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name "Test-GPO" -Key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" -ValueName NoWinKeys -Value 1 -Type DWORD
```